# Should I need to convert ordered numerical data into categorical for encoding or normalize it?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, data-science, feature-selection, feature-engineering

I'm working on a dataset that has both numerical and categorical columns. One of the numerical columns is `fare rates ($)` which has just 4 distinct values (`200`, `400`, `600` and `800`). I have done feature scaling on other numerical features but I'm stuck here to decide whether should I need to apply `normalization` here or make it categorical to `encode` this feature. I want to use Neural Networks, if I treat it as a numerical feature, the weights for this feature will affect the output. If anyone has any leads then please help me in this regard.
Thanks

I'm trying to find a perfect solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use it as numerical feature, it should give you a better result. I

Comment: Can I get to know the reason why should I use it as a numerical feature or why not use it as a categorical feature?